# Jedi fails on autocomplete in sublime text

Tags: sublime-text-plugin, python-jedi

Jedi fails on autocomplete in sublime text for some cases:

```python
import os

def x(y):
    print(y)

print(x)
f = open('1.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8'). # fail on dot

from datetime import d # fail on module import
```

I've got this error in both cases:

```
...
  File "/Users/rmerkushin/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/sublime-jedi/jedi/parser/__init__.py", line 267, in parse
    root_node = super(ParserWithRecovery, self).parse(self._tokenize(tokenizer))
  File "/Users/rmerkushin/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/sublime-jedi/jedi/parser/__init__.py", line 146, in parse
    self.remove_last_newline()
  File "/Users/rmerkushin/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/sublime-jedi/jedi/parser/__init__.py", line 227, in remove_last_newline
    assert newline.value.endswith('\n')
AssertionError
```

How to fix this issue?

P.S.: jedi version - 0.10.0, Sublime Text - 3126 (Python 3.3.6)

Comment: With Jedi 0.9.0 i catch this error: "
  File "/Users/rmerkushin/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/sublime-jedi/jedi/_compatibility.py", line 40, in find_module_py33
    module_file = open(module_path, 'rb')
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/python3.3.zip/datetime.pyo'"

Comment: I'm write my own sublime text plugin. I registered an error here: https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/896